# Integral inequality involving modulus

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f,g \in C^{1}([0,1])$ with $f(x) \ge c > 0$ and $g$ can take negative values.

**Question:** Is it true that

$$ \left| \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g(x)~dx \right| \ge  c \left| \int_{0}^{1}g(x)~dx\right| $$

I think that it could be false if we take a $g$ which is oscillating and $f$ chosen appropriately so that  the integral of the product is $0$ but the integral of $g$ is non-zero (the oscillation will have to be so that the area bounded by the curve and the x-axis in the region where it is negative must be larger than the area where it is positive).

I am not entirely sure if my intuition is correct however so I would appreciate a counterexample or a proof. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your intuition about why it does not hold is indeed very correct. Take

$$f(x)=2\pi x+1,\quad g(x)=\frac{\sin(2\pi x)}{2\pi x+1}.$$

Then $f,g\in C^1([0,1])$, $f(x)\geq1=c$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and

$$\int_0^1f(x)g(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^1\sin(2\pi x)~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\sin\theta~\mathrm{d}\theta=0,$$

while

$$\int_0^1 g(x)~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\sin\theta}{\theta+1}~\mathrm{d}\theta\geq0.07$$

by WolframAlpha. Consequently

$$\left\lvert\int_0^1f(x)g(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert<c\left\lvert\int_0^1g(x)~\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert.$$

Comment: Thank you! I was having trouble constructing the right oscillation

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion is not true for any fixed nonconstant function $f(x).$ We will apply the property that if for $u,v\in C[0,1]$ we have $\int\limits_0^1u(x)\,x^n\,dx=\int\limits_0^1v(x)\,x^n\,dx$ for all $n\ge 0,$ then $u=v.$ The conclusion follows from the Weierstrass theorem on the density of polynomials in $C[0,1].$

WLOG we may assume that $\int\limits_0^1 f(x)\,dx=1.$ Since $f\not\equiv 1$  there is $n\ge 1$ such that
$$a_n:=\int\limits_0^1 f(x)x^n\,dx\neq \int\limits_0^1 x^n\,dx={1\over n+1}$$
Let $g(x)=x^n-a_n.$ Then
$$\int\limits_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx =0,\quad \int\limits_0^1g(x)\,dx={1\over n+1}-a_n\neq 0$$